# Change docker run command to accept changes to CSV files

Tags: python, docker, volume

just to explain: my docker container is currently set up to "refresh/update" itself every time i upload or change a  python file, for instance: "main.py"

This is exactly I want it and that's beautiful, thanks to this command:

```
' -v ~/fastapi_websocket:/fastapi_websocket '
```

Here are all my 3 docker commands which i use to make it up and running:

```
1. docker build -t fastapiserver-websocket .

2. docker run -d -e PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 -v ~/fastapi_websocket:/fastapi_websocket --env-file env_vars.env --name run-fastapi-websocket -p 5080:80 fastapiserver-websocket

3. docker logs --tail 100 -f run-fastapi-websocket
```

So once I type in those 3 commands, I can keep uploading new files to the server without stopping/removing the container/image and then create a new one, docker does it itself automatically.

NOW: now i added a script to my python app that writes data to a CSV file, in case you know python or not, here is the function:

```
def write_data_to_CSV(machine_ID, leli, acc_y, mag_x):
    with open('/i_want_my_CSV_inside_here/sensor_data_excel.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
        filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

        filewriter.writerow([get_current_time(), machine_ID, leli, acc_y, mag_x])
```

So the issue here is that when new files are written to the CSV file, the docker container updates/refreshes itself because I have told the container to do so using the command I showed above.

My question is then: is it possible to change this line:

```
docker run -d -e PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 -v ~/fastapi_websocket:/fastapi_websocket --env-file env_vars.env --name run-fastapi-websocket -p 5080:80 fastapiserver-websocket
```

To accept changes to the CSV file without refreshing the container?

Comment: What causes the restart (just running an ordinary Python container with a bind mount won't do it)?  Would a non-Docker virtual environment be easier to work with as a development setup?

Comment: ' -v ~/fastapi_websocket:/fastapi_websocket '   setting causes the docker container to reload it ..

Comment: That option just replaces the content in the image with the corresponding directory on the host (so you're not running the application in the image at all, and the setup is potentially extremely different from what would run in production).  It doesn't on its own cause any sort of reloading.

Comment: So what about this then?

'docker run -d -e PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 -v ~/fastapi_websocket:/fastapi_websocket -v ~/CSV_files:/a_CSV_file.csv --env-file env_vars.env --name run-fastapi-websocket -p 5080:80 fastapiserver-websocket'

I tried to create a new volume where i place the CSV file, but i get the message:

'this is missing: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../CSV_files/a_CSV_file.csv''

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: solved it.

Here is the answer:

I mounted a new volume outside the app folder: `-v ~/CSV_files:/CSV_files`

python side:

```
with open("../CSV_files/a_CSV_file.csv", 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```